# separate characters from borders after thresholding

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I would like to separate characters from borders after thresholding the images:

Original image

[image: Original Image]

Touching areas

[image: Touching areas]

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

I'm using python and OpenCV to do the thresholding. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is part of the code that makes the threshold

```
def threshold_image(img):
   gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   resized_img = cv2.resize(gray_img
    , None
    , fx=5.0
    , fy=5.0
    , interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    resized_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_img,(5,5),0)#(5,5)

   equalized_img = cv2.equalizeHist(resized_img)
   # height of the image
   alto = int(resized_img.shape[0])  # shape[0] = rows
   # width of the image 
   ancho = int(resized_img.shape[1])  # shape[1] = cols

   reduced = cv2.cvtColor(reduce_colors(cv2.cvtColor(equalized_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), 6), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   ret, mask = cv2.threshold(reduced, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)#64
   cv2.imwrite('licence_plate_mask.png', mask)

   return mask
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains links to multiple off-site locations necessary to answer the question.

Comment: I don't see any external links? Those are stack-hosted images that they did not know how to embed for some reason, but your question is vague because you have not provided an attempt. Please post any relevant Python code that you have written to assist everyone.

Comment: I added the code that makes the thresholding to the image, the result of this code is the "Original Image" which I want to process to obtain the last one.

Comment: I'd suggest trying [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) for a better approach on making a suitable structuring element for morphing the image

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) operation to your mask to disconnect the selected area.

You should be careful to not disconnect the "H" when eroding, you could change your kernel to affect the shape vertically the most.

You can read more about math morphology operators [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology).

Comment: I don't think erosion is the correct way to go here. Have you tried it on the sample image?